# Parse Paging Results From GeoPoint Query

Tags: parse-platform, data-paging

We are attempting to page through results from a PFQuery that includes a GeoPoint. We are seeing duplication and inconsistencies in the returned records.

For example:

```
PFGeoPoint *geoPoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:41.90585396476684 longitude:-87.64885427269438]; [photo whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:geoPoint withinMiles:75];

photo.limit = 100; 
photo.skip = 100;
```

will return different results for two users at the same location.

Is this a technical limitation on Parse?

Answer (score 0):

The query also contained a sort:

```
[photo orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
```

Removing the sort produces correct paging without duplication. Results are returned sorted by distance.